# How to prevent default on a link inside of its element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

When I click on link it goes on top of the page and I want to remove it by not calling a function( I figured out that one ).

does not work:

```
echo    "<a href=\"javascript: function(){ alert(\'\'); }\">Open images</a>";
```

this works:

```
echo    "<a href=\"javascript: alert(\"\")\">Open images</a>";
```

My now working code:

```
$('a').on( 'click', function( event ){
            event.preventDefault();
});
```

This all is simplefied (removed classes and ID so its easier to understand).

And I want something like this:

```
echo "<a href=\"javascript: function(event){ event.preventDefault(); }\">Open images</a>";
```

of course it doesnt work.

Im doing all this because I want that little pointy finger when I hover link.

Comment: There is appropriate CSS for the 'pointy finger': `cursor:pointer`

Comment: If all you want is 'pointy fingure' use can CSS property `cursor:pointer` on intented element.

Comment: `<a href="javascript:;">Hello</a>` should do the job.

Answer (score 1):

I think its better to have an click event that you already have above in your code. But since your need is something like this, below is one option try it

```
 echo '<a href="#" onclick="stop(event);function stop(event){event.preventDefault();}">Open image</a>';
```

Hope this helps
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The "pointy finger" is a CSS [`cursor` value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/cursor):

```css
elem {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

With this you can simply modify your HTML to something like:

```
<span class="clickable"></span>
```

Using the following CSS:

```css
.clickable {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Then use jQuery to target that particular class:

```
$('.clickable').on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: My goal is to combine all js code in a link attributes so it looks nice and tidy.

Comment: @Cirvis JS Code in **href** attributes isn't what I'd call *tidy*. What is wrong with jQuery's event listeners?

Comment: I've been writing like that for a long time and at one point I got lost, so something had to change. And now Im trying to assign as much scirpt to elements themselves as possible so I know where to find the right script.

Comment: @Cirvis I'm afraid that's really bad practice. What if you have an element on five different pages which use the same piece of JavaScript? You'd end up having to use 5 copied JavaScript snippets and if you ever needed to change one you'd have to change it 5 different times. With an event listener you'd only have the one JavaScript snippet and it'd be so much easier to maintain.